# Does ios7 come with standard icons?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I'm coming from Android world and new to iOS. Android ships certain icons with the SDK. Standard stuff like edit, create, save, favorite. Does iOS come with these icons? If no, where is a good place the community gets common icons for share, save, favorite (star), etc?

Answer (score 2):

Use the:

```
- (id)initWithBarButtonSystemItem:(UIBarButtonSystemItem)systemItem target:(id)target action:(SEL)action;
```

Method to add UIBarButtons to your toolbar.

```
UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSearch target:target action:action];
```

These are the types available

```
UIBarButtonSystemItemDone,
UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel,
UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit,  
UIBarButtonSystemItemSave,  
UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd,
UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace,
UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace,
UIBarButtonSystemItemCompose,
UIBarButtonSystemItemReply,
UIBarButtonSystemItemAction,
UIBarButtonSystemItemOrganize,
UIBarButtonSystemItemBookmarks,
UIBarButtonSystemItemSearch,
UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh,
UIBarButtonSystemItemStop,
UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera,
UIBarButtonSystemItemTrash,
UIBarButtonSystemItemPlay,
UIBarButtonSystemItemPause,
UIBarButtonSystemItemRewind,
UIBarButtonSystemItemFastForward,
```

Comment: This is only for UIBarButtonItems; it's not a general solution for other places in a UI where you'd be using UIButtons. There's no general class or method that will vend you the actual system icons as UIImages.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have a set of standard buttons.

Look for `UIBarButton items` or `UITabBar Button` ( you can see directly from the .xib view)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not trying to add these icons as bar button items, as far as I know there is no way to get the images directly. However, there is a [font](https://github.com/AKIRA-MIYAKE/iOS7-icon-font) you can use to replicate iOS7 icons. [Here's](http://ios7-icon-font-demo.herokuapp.com) the list of all images provided by the font